# Why NoSuchBeanDefinedException while running Spring Integration test

Tags: spring, integration-testing, context-configuration

I have a Spring Boot project for which one of the developers has written Integration tests against an in-memory DB. Here is some background before I put my question :
We have following Maven modules :
1) **web-persistence** : which store all entities and interfaces and corresponding implementations. All these classes are in package `com.mycompany.persistence`.
2) **web-services** : which stores all our rest controllers and spring security related classes. These are all in package `com.mycompany.services`
3) web-services module has maven module dependency on web-persistence module.
4) In web-services module we have defined a service `UserContextServiceImpl` which is implementation of interface `IUserContextService`. This service basically encapsulates Spring's SecurityContextHolder functionality by exposing only those parts of a current user related information which is needed through its methods so that everywhere we don't have to use SecurityContextHolder. The implementation class is annotated with @Service("userContextService").
5) Interface `IUserContextService` is in persistence module. There is another class **`AppDependecyHeper`** in persistence module which implements `ApplicationContextAware` and returns UserContextService's concrete instance by calling `appContext.getBean('userContextService')` where `appContext` is holding `ApplicationContext` when application is initialized.
6) Now we don't want to expose Spring Security classes in persistence module(for reasons which are out of context here) and hence above arrangement of getting current user information through a service by calling `getBean() method of applicationContext` in persistence layer class `AppDependencyHelper`. This information is then used to update audit fields createdBy and modifiedBy using   an `EntityListener.`
7) Actual application uses only single `ApplicationContext` where both persistence layer classes and web controllers are loaded in one single spring context.
8) Everything works fine when application runs. However when our integration test Runs the call `appContext.getBean('userContextService')` fails and throws `NosuchBeanDefinitionException` as it is unable to find the bean with name 'userContextService'
9) Now finally the code of our integration Test (only giving relevant details) which is located in `com.mycompany.persistence.embeddeddb` package:

```
  @Runwith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ConfigurationContext 
  class MyEntityTest{

        @Configuration
        @ComponentScan("com.mycompany.persistence")  
        public static class Config{
              .....
        }
        .....//code which eventually gives call to  
        AppDependencyHelper's method which in turn tries to retrieve userContextService Bean.
  }
```

Now the questions :
1) Why it fails to retrieve the bean? I have tried adding`com.mycompany.services` like below

`@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.persistence","com.mycompany.services"})`
 but to no avail.
2) What I am able to understand by reading whatever I got is that `@ContextConfiguration` needs to be provided with either XML files or Annotated classes or WebApplicationInitializers(in my case as we are having only single ApplicationContext) to create an `ApplicationContext` from @Configuration classes. However I cannot do that as maven starts complaining about circular dependency which is rightly so as my `@Service` annotated class  `UserContextServiceImpl` is in web-services module which is dependent on web-persistence module already where the test case class is written.
3) The only solution I can think of is moving all integrations test classes to web-services module so that I can tell `@ConfigurationContext` all the classes from which it should create an `ApplicationContext`.Am I right?

Last point : The `ApplicationContext` class is of type `GenericApplciationContext` when I run tests. When I run application its obviously `AnnotatedEmbeddedWebApplicationContext`

**please let me know if there is any solution to this problem?**

Comment: Just to be sure: How's your class called, that implements `IUserContextService`? Did you stick with default bean naming conventions or did you give it an alternative bean name using `@Component(value = "userContextService")`?

Comment: I feel like we are neglecting to refer to the correct sections of the Spring Manual in helping you to solve your problem.... by the same token this question is very large

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm guessing you are trying to use a component from your web-service module in your integration tests. If that's the case, than yes, you should move your integration test cases to your web-service module - as you've already suggested in your question.

**EDIT**: You should really rethink your design, because you have a circular dependency problem here: Your `web-service` module depends on `web-persistence`, but the implementation of your `IUserContextService` in `web-persistence` is found in `web-service`.

You should probably move your `IUserContextService` (and all your integration tests) to your `web-service` package.

Comment: Ok. great. But can you please tell me why it doesn't work even if I add the package of web-services in ComponentScan? If I add higher level package (com.mycompany), which contains other Component (and its friends ) classes, it gives different errors while the test initializes. But when I add my service package it initializes but breaks at runtime. Is ComponentScan ignoring it?

Comment: Also even if hypothetically I solve this problem the problem of setting up SecurityContext still remains and the reason we have this problem is that we dont want to put Spring Security dependency in persistence module. So another reason to move this to web-services so that Spring Security can be enabled in my integration test correct?

Comment: In regard to your first comment: Your test fails at initialization, when Spring cannot find an `@Autowire`d collaborator in your `@Component` classes. Your test fails at runtime, when you try to get a Bean from your fully built Spring container using `appContext.getBean('userContextService')` which simply does not exist

Comment: Alright I was able to resolve this by adding an implementation class in persistence package which actually returned hard coded string. Not sure if this is right approach as this cannot be called a pure integration test.

Comment: Make sure your `IUserContextService` stub sits in `src/test/java`

Comment: No At runtime when actual application works as I have implementation in web-services module and we have only single application context. But for tests it doesn't scan web-services package. so introduced stub implementation in src/test/java in com.mycompany.persistence package which worked out.